# StaleStateException when changing id in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Very new to NHibernate so I expect there will be a quick fix here.

The code I'm looking at has an unorthodox design.

```
public class Partner
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;} //note the set is not private
    public virtual String Name { get; set;}
}
```

and is mapped with FluentNhibernate's Automappings

When `Partner` is created its Id is 0 but when 
I call Flush to persist to the db:

```
        CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
        CurrentSession.Flush();
```

I get a  `Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1` StaleStateException

I'm assuming its because NHibernate doesn't like me changing the Primary Key, Id.
In this case I need to. How can I configure NH to let me achieve this abomination?

Comment: Why don't you delete the existing object and add a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the update with HQL:

```
session.CreateQuery("update Partner set Id = :newId where Id = :oldId")
       .SetParameter("newId", newId)
       .SetParameter("oldId", oldId)
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

I suggest that you `Evict` the entity from the session, or use a stateless one if you are going to update the Id.